# How to specify typescript conditional type based on a function return type in the arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a function like this:

```
export const getValue = (
  options: Options = { someMapping, someFunction }
): string | MyType => {
  ...
  return someFunction({ ...someData });
};
```

Right now, the return type is string or MyType.

This is because someFunction can either return string or MyType.

Is there a way to use TypeScript conditional type to return the correct type based on what someFunction actually returns?

**[Additional Info after first post]**:

Here is the definition of Options type:

```
export interface Options {
  someMapping: MappingType;
  someFunc: (data: MyType) => MyType | string;
}
```

The someFunc param is a function that expects a MyType param.

Here are two actual functions I pass in depends on the situation:

```
const myFunc = (data: MyType): string => {
  return data.someProperty;
};

const myFunc = (data: MyType): MyType => {
  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you can do is type `someFunction` and use function overloading.  The `Options` makes it a little more complicated, but something like this should work:

```
type MyFunc<T extends MyType | string> = () => T;

interface Options<T extends MyType | string> {
  someMapping: WhateverTypeThisIs;
  someFunc: MyFunc<T>;
}

function getValue(options: Options<MyType>): MyType;
function getValue(options: Options<string>): string;
function getValue<T extends MyType | string>(options: Options<T>): T {
   return options.someFunc();
}
```

So now you should get typings for something like this:

```
const myTypeOptions: Options<MyType> = {
   someMapping: {},
   someFunc: () => ({ myParam: "MyValue" })
};
const myStringOptions: Options<string> = {
   someMapping: {},
   someFunc: () => "Hello"
};
const myTypeValue = getValue(myOptions); // myNumberValue is of type { myParam: string };
const myStringValue = getValue(myStringOptions); // myStringValue is a string;
```

This is of course dependent on the fact that the function in question *always* returns a `MyType` or *always* returns a `string`.  If it changes depending on the parameters of the function, then it will always be a `MyType | string` because Typescript would not be able to determine that.  It would be up the caller to figure out what it is.

EDIT:

Based on the scenario you presented, something like this might help.  You can create to types of `MyFunc`.

```
type MyTypeFunc = (myType: MyType) => MyType;
type MyStringFunc = (myType: MyType) => string;

interface MyOptions {
  someMapping: WatheverTypeThisIs;
}

interface MyTypeOptions extends MyOptions {
  someFunc: MyTypeFunc;
}

interface MyStringOptions extends MyOptions {
  someFunc: MyStringFunc;
}

function getValue(options: MyTypeOptions): MyType;
function getValue(options: MyStringOptions): string;
function getValue(options: MyTypeOptions | MyStringOptions): T {
   return options.someFunc();
}
```

Now, whenever you call it you can create or options like this:

```
const myTypeOptions: MyTypeOptions = {
  someMapping: {},
  someFunc: (myType) => myType
}

const myStringOptions: MyStringOptions = {
  someMapping: {},
  someFunc: (myType) => myType.someProperty
}

const myTypeValue = getValue(myTypeOptions); // myTypeValue will be of type MyType
const myStringValue = getValue(myStringOptions); // myStringValue will be of type string
```

Comment: Hi @DeeV, in my situation, MyFunc only takes in an argument of MyType.  I have added additional info on my post.  I am hoping to find is some conditional typing based on the actual type myFunc returns...

Comment: @techguy2000  I updated my answer.  The trick is to define two types of functions.

Comment: I don't want to define more functions if I don't have to.  I am trying to figure out how conditional type works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641731/typescript-conditional-type-complains-type-not-assignable  Do you have ideas?

Comment: I ended up using function overloading.  I wonder if typescript conditional type is all that useful...

Answer (score 0):

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20MyFunc%3CT%20extends%20number%20%7C%20string%3E%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Options%3CT%20extends%20number%20%7C%20string%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20someMapping%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20someFunc%3A%20MyFunc%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20getValue%3CT%20extends%20number%20%7C%20string%3E(options%3A%20Options%3CT%3E)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20string%20%3D%20getValue(%7B%0D%0A%20%20someMapping%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20someFunc%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%22%22%0D%0A%7D)) you can let typescript infer return type. Function overloading provided by @DeeV works as well.