# How to select a string member of an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the below definition

```js
interface IAutoCompleteInputProps<T> {
    textMember: keyof T;
    imageMember: keyof T;
    data: T[];
}
```

But I also want to ensure the value of `T[textMember]` must be `string`, too.
How can I achieve that?

**=== Update:**
After I implemented the @R Pasha's answer, when I try to access the `textMember` by `a.data[a.textMember]` (I expect it will be a string) but the IDE says that

```
(property) value: T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never; }[keyof T]]
Type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never; }[keyof T]]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'T[T[keyof T] extends string ? keyof T : never]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

I can cast it to string, but just want to know why? Thanks

PS the code that I got error

```js
function Application<T>(props: IAutoCompleteInputProps<T>) {
  const x = props.data[0][props.textMember]; // x here is not string
}
```

Here is [Playground Link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwArwPaXsREAzgDwAqAfFALxTqIDGA1mQDRQDeUAUFL1ANoBpKCiiMIILADMopALoAuWULlQIAD2ARkAE0JRCCFKigB+KMKXIIANwjxuAX37jJM+eQDcXLii3wpAEN6aABJAEEAV2AsAGEsAFswABsILVDkMGjMHBIKdh4+LU0AWQgEgCN7JVdpWCM0HNx8IjIvQt5EBMDUCDLK6rEJOtJvPigdQOBApVJ+OW9HHylI5Hp8LGQocLAUhinETbaACjBsMEIlCOi4xJS0iAys4Ca88gBKDkL6TcModWoUDOuQAdJNpvwAAxyfjAi4g4rAfpVeALKAAenRUGIAFp-lAABb2aCIfTILDAAwNVDfX6UkBKQxINCA9SeDFY3GycDQADkc04QhEW1q7kUykEqg0Wl0+iZxjMFigVls9nZzlFsjkcl5IjJFKggUIhEQqGQgQqqSgMWtPKgvPlaF5IK4S18yH8QRC3MgAEYvrwpARkjpfVZIgN4OzMdi8aSoMgIyjCkGICGAEyM6mLHypSkAq5RGLxJJ5x6ZbLnPI832UGgFXiI5H2ZX21Mh328tgxrnt0NQBKRP5VKnMmmdbq9ZvwJS8vvpruFcEzARyV1AA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316)

```
type StringProperties<T> = Pick<T, { 
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never 
}[keyof T]>;

interface IAutoCompleteInputProps<T>{
    textMember: keyof StringProperties<T>;
    imageMember: keyof T;
    data: T[];
}

interface Type1 {
  field1: number; // <- is number
  field2: string;
}

let x : IAutoCompleteInputProps<Type1> = {
  textMember : 'field1', // <- field1 must be string
  imageMember: 'field2',
  data: []

}
```

Comment: Great! This works when I input value for the props but when I'm trying to extract the value of text member there is still an error in the Visual studio code. I updated question. Do you know why?

Comment: hmm, interesting. can you make a stackblitz.com ?

Comment: yes, I created a playground link, updated in post, because link is too long

Comment: it seems Typescript doesn't support this scenario, more discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641731/typescript-conditional-type-complains-type-not-assignable

Answer (score 0):

Pick properties of string value using this helper:

```
type PropertyOfValue<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V
    ? K
    : never
}[keyof T];
```

Usage:

```
interface Type1 {
  field1: number; 
  field2: string;
}

const props: IAutoCompleteInputProps<Type1> = {
  data: [
    { field1: 42, field2: 'foo' }
  ],
  imageMember: 'field1',
  textMember: 'field2'
}

props.textMember; // "field2"
props.data[0][props.textMember]; // string
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEECuYD2BhHAWwAcAbCSVEY7ABSh2IGcAeAFQD5kBvAKGQHJIADzABZCIQBG0AFzJ6jaGACeAeRgA1OKUwR2AGmRMwUUAHMOAbn6DghOOYgTpc5AGsIKnDGRsbgsgAJnBgcPJsANoAujYAvry8qsQoiilQqhrauvpsRppcALw8tpEA0sigHl4%20ftEAtAD8EeXRyBCiECBBTMiatgKNyGUDyPIgEABu0LxxkZ7evmyxiaCQsIgobCopAIwlAjDAEKRBu%20OYrlBWyLZHJ0EATPImZiDm8YkIOCAmyMQMZjyDDYfBEMgUCBUGhgNKsbZ7IoHYKhcLISKjbjIe6nc7IAAsjyMOKe8gA5DAcDgycgEgJogZbPZHM5JDIoOSSbsyYyBCJxGy3BTjqdHmTZokAYwmAA6fkudk3AD0SuQACISY81bwpcwZSEwpEAAzRSK62XywVQWLIFXGUwWIA)

Comment: Thanks @Karol Majewski, your answer is somewhat similar to the first one. When I use it in another Generic function, it still cannot be deducted to `string`.  Any idea? I updated my question