# How can I unpack a return type that is a Typescript union and may be an array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function with a return type that looks something like the following:

```
type FuncReturns = TypeA | [any, TypeB];
```

where...

```
interface TypeA {
    name: string;
    count: number;
}

interface TypeB {
    color: string;
    volume: number;
    edges: number;
}

const myAwesomeFunc = (val : string | number, obj : object = {}) : FuncReturns=>{
    switch(typeof val){
       case "string" : {
           return {
               name: val,
               count: 1
           }
       } case "number" : {
           return [obj, {
               color: "blue",
               volume: 6,
               edges: 6
           }]
       } default {// should never be used in this way
            throw new Error("This is nonsense.")
       }
    }
}
```

... should be unpack-able (destructurable) both like this...

```
const {name, count} = myAwesomeFunc(someValue);
```

... and like this...

```
const [object, {color, volume, edges}] = myAwesomeFunc(someOtherValue);
```

Based on some internal logic, the function may return an object, TypeA, which I would like to unpack or an array, TypeB, which I would also like to unpack. Unfortunately, rather than accepting the array unpacking operator as one of the possible methods that could be applied to the return type, I end up with an error that states the union type `is not an array type`. I can think of several workarounds for my use case, but I'd like to know if there is an established way to solve this problem.

**NOTE:**
As alekxsor duly noted, there are really only two branches I want the function to travel down: (1) string val to return object and (2) number val to return array. The optimal solution would enable typechecking such that when provided a string, the return type expected would be an object and so on.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```typescript
type FuncReturns = TypeA | [any, TypeB]

const myAwesomeFunc = (val : string | number, obj : object = {}): FuncReturns {...}
```

This signature effectively telling that in concrete types it can do any of the following:

```typescript
  (val: string, obj: ...) => TypeA
  (val: string, obj: ...) => [any, TypeB]
  (val: number, obj: ...) => TypeA
  (val: number, obj: ...) => [any, TypeB]
```

That is defenitily not the thing that it does in practice. The most concise way to convey the exact meaning is to use [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```javascript
function myAwesomeFunc(val: string): TypeA
function myAwesomeFunc(val: number, obj: object): [any, TypeB]
function myAwesomeFunc(val: string | number, obj?: object): TypeA | [any, TypeB] {
  // actual implementation
}
```

---

Update for `const` version:

To make it work with `const` syntax you can define it either as a callable interface or as an intersection of function types:

```typescript
interface MyAwesomeFunc {
  (val: string): TypeA
  (val: number, obj: object): [any, TypeB]
}

or

type MyAwesomeFunc 
  = (((val: string) => TypeA) 
  & ((val: number, obj: object) => [any, TypeB]))

const myAwesomeFunc: MyAwesomeFunc = (val: string | number, obj?: object): any {
 // ...
}
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/w62yGw)

Comment: Yeah, I realize that it is essentially describing four functions. I had also previously tried defining via function interfaces the actual two paths. What is the best way to function overload when using const = style? Would I be best off overloading on an _myAwesomeFunc the assigning const to the final overload?

Comment: You can make it either "callable interface" with overloading or an intersection of function types.

Comment: I haven't been able to get function type intersections working for me. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). Instead of noting `val` as `string | number`, mark it as a generic and then use a conditional type to note that the return type depends on the type of `val`.

```
const myAwesomeFunc = <T extends string | number>(val: T, obj: object = {}):
  T extends string ? TypeA : T extends number ? [any, TypeB] : never => {/* ... */};
```

This looks a bit complex, so let's break it down - we introduce a generic type parameter `T` that must be assignable to `string | number` (in practice, it must be either a string or a number). For the return type, we use a nested ternary:

```
T extends string
  ? TypeA /* if T is a string, we'll return TypeA */
  : T extends number
    ? [any, TypeB] /* if T is a number, we'll return an array with TypeB */
    : never /* this tells TS that this function can't return any other type */
```

I tried this on the TS playground and couldn't get it to compile correctly without using function overloading (see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641731/typescript-conditional-type-complains-type-not-assignable) for more context). Here's a working version:

```
function myAwesomeFunc<T extends string | number>(val: T, obj?: object): T extends string ? TypeA : T extends number ? [any, TypeB] : never;
function myAwesomeFunc<T extends string | number>(val: T, obj: object = {}): TypeA | [any, TypeB] {
  switch(typeof val){
    case "string" : {
      return {
        name: val,
        count: 1,
      };
    }
    case "number": {
      return [obj, {
        color: "blue",
        volume: 6,
        edges: 6,
      }];
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error("This is nonsense");
    }
  }
}
```

The first "overload" notes the conditional return type, and the second just marks the actual possible return types. Using this version, you can do

```
const { name, count } = myAwesomeFunc('Hello, world!');
const [obj, { color, volume, edges }] = myAwesomeFunc(123);
```

and everything should typecheck as expected.

Comment: Ha just realized @jcalz commented on that linked thread as well, perhaps they can shed some light on why the `const` version doesn't typecheck?

Comment: I think it's probably because you can't overload on const.