# Typescript conditional type for constructor options does not work when passed a generic

Tags: typescript

I work with a library (that I have no control over) that has roughly the following API interface:

```js
interface ObjectWithKey {
  key: string | number;
}

interface SelectorOptions<T> {
  getKey?: (item: T) => string;
  // ...other options
}

interface SelectorOptionsWithRequiredGetKey<T> {
  getKey: (item: T) => string;
  // ...other options
}

class Selector<T> {
  constructor(
    options: T extends ObjectWithKey
      ? SelectorOptions<T>
      : SelectorOptionsWithRequiredGetKey<T>
  ) {
    console.log("constructed");
  }
}
```

In summary, you can create a `Selector` object, but the options type the constructor expects changes depending on if `T` has a `key` property.

If I provide a specific type to `Selector` the code works and compiles as expected:

```js
interface Foo {
  id: string;
}

const selector = new Selector<Foo>({
  getKey: (foo) => foo.id
});
```

However, if I try to pass a generic into `Selector` I get a confusing typescript compiler error:

```js
function createGenericSelector<T>(getKey: (item: T) => string) {
  return new Selector<T>({ getKey });
}

const selector = createGenericSelector<Foo>((foo) => foo.id);

// Argument of type '{ getKey: (item: T) => string; }' is not 
// assignable to parameter of type 'T extends ObjectWithKey ? 
// SelectorOptions<T> : SelectorOptionsWithRequiredGetKey<T>
```

`{ getKey: (item: T) => string; }` should be a valid options object, regardless of whether `T` has a `key` property or not. So what gives? Why doesn't this work? Any way I can fudge my generic somehow to satisfy the compiler?

Here is a link to a codesandbox with all of the above code: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-lamport-6d7jm6?file=/src/index.ts:733-795

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript Conditional Type complains Type not assignable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641731/typescript-conditional-type-complains-type-not-assignable)

Comment: Not really - I can't change the library code to use function overloading, it's third party library that I'm stuck with.

Comment: As this is an official limitation as mentioned in the github issue, the simplest workaround you can do is to opt-out type checking by adding `as any` after `{ getKey }`.